# Could you explain why one line of logging could be missing here?

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, task, task-parallel-library

I don't really understand how this could happen. I'm sure that this is very volatile and not always exactly the same.

I have the following code, there is one core method and another method to call the core methods simultaneously by starting multiple Tasks, each Task calling 1 core method.

```
//here is the core method
public static bool ImportToSql(string targetConnectionString, IEnumerable<SyncedItem> accessFileItems)
{                        
        var completelyOk = true;
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(targetConnectionString))
        {                
            foreach (var a in accessFileItems)
            {
                Log.WriteOnToday($"Syncing file: {a.Filename} ...");
                var query = "some query here ...";
                var retries = -1;
                while (++retries <= 10)
                {
                    if(retries > 0)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(60000);
                        Log.WriteOnToday($"Retrying to sync the file: \"{a.Filename}\" ({retries}/{10}) ...");
                    }
                    var r = ...;//do something here returning bool result
                    completelyOk &= r;
                    if (r)
                    {                            
                        break;
                    } else if(retries == 10)
                    {
                        Log.WriteOnToday($"FAILED to synce the file \"{a.Filename}\" after {10} retries");
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        return completelyOk;
}

//here is another method, actually the test data is grouped in 2 groups 
//corresponding to 2 Tasks
public static async Task<bool> ParallelImportToSql(string targetConnectionString, IEnumerable<SyncedItem> accessFileItems)
{
        IEnumerable<Task<bool>> tasks = accessFileItems.Select((e, i) => new { e, i })
                                        .GroupBy(e => e.i % 2, (key,items) => items.Select(e => e.e))
                                        .Select(g => Task.Run<bool>(() => ImportToSql(targetConnectionString, g)));
        return (await Task.WhenAll(tasks)).All(e => e);
    }
```

So you can see that there is one call to `Log.WriteOnToday` to log "Retrying ..." and I expect that should always be called (per my test the `r` is always false) and write exactly one corresponding line to the output file. So if it runs 10 times, there should be 10 lines. But actually there is one line missing in the output result. I really wonder how that could happen, could you analyze the code here and identify which could be wrong?

Here is the output result (written by `Log.WriteOnToDay` for "Retrying..."):

```
4/12/2018 5:28:05 PM - HO-IT1 >> Syncing file: \\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\11_04_2018\cust.mdb ...
4/12/2018 5:29:05 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\11_04_2018\cust.mdb" (1/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:29:05 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\SVR\cust.mdb" (1/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:30:45 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\11_04_2018\cust.mdb" (2/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:32:25 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\11_04_2018\cust.mdb" (3/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:32:25 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\SVR\cust.mdb" (3/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:34:05 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\SVR\cust.mdb" (4/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:34:05 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\11_04_2018\cust.mdb" (4/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:35:45 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\SVR\cust.mdb" (5/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:35:45 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\11_04_2018\cust.mdb" (5/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:37:25 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\SVR\cust.mdb" (6/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:37:26 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\11_04_2018\cust.mdb" (6/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:39:06 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\SVR\cust.mdb" (7/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:39:06 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\11_04_2018\cust.mdb" (7/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:40:46 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\SVR\cust.mdb" (8/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:40:46 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\11_04_2018\cust.mdb" (8/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:42:26 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\SVR\cust.mdb" (9/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:42:26 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\11_04_2018\cust.mdb" (9/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:44:06 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\SVR\cust.mdb" (10/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:44:06 PM - HO-IT1 >> Retrying to sync the file: "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\11_04_2018\cust.mdb" (10/10) ...
4/12/2018 5:44:46 PM - HO-IT1 >> FAILED to synce the file "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\SVR\cust.mdb" after 10 retries
4/12/2018 5:44:46 PM - HO-IT1 >> FAILED to synce the file "\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\11_04_2018\cust.mdb" after 10 retries
```

There are just 2 files (mdb files to be synced to sql) including `\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\SVR\cust.mdb` and `\\192.168.0.144\DataKH_311\11_04_2018\cust.mdb`. The second file has all 10 logging lines output OK (as expected) BUT the first file has just 9 logging lines, the second line (corresponding to the second retry) is missing (for no reason). If looking at the time, you can see that there is almost a double gap (compared to other continuous pairs of logging lines of the same file) between the first (1/10) and the third (3/10) logging lines (for the first file I mentioned above). So looks like it's not just a simple by-passing.

It's not very important to miss that logging line, but in some other case if something important (some line of code) is by-passed here, that could cause a very hidden error (and of course that's very serious and unacceptable).

### Update

The problem might be in the `Log.WriteOnToDay`, here is its code:

```
public static class Log
{        
    public static string LastWrittenLogFileName { get; private set; }
    public static void WriteOnToday(string message, bool prependedWithDate = true, bool includeMachineInfo = true, string logFilePrefix = "log_")
    {            
        Write(message, prependedWithDate, includeMachineInfo, string.Format(@"Logs\{0}{1:ddMMyyyy}.txt", logFilePrefix, DateTime.Now));
    }
    public static void Write(string message, bool prependedWithDate = true, bool includeMachineInfo = true, string filename = "log.txt")
    {
        //check for relative path in a simple way
        if (Path.GetPathRoot(filename).Length < 3)
        {
            if (_currentDirectory == null)
            {
                _currentDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
            }
            filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(_currentDirectory, filename);
        }
        LastWrittenLogFileName = filename;
        var dateText = "";
        var machineInfo = "";
        if (prependedWithDate) dateText = DateTime.Now + " - ";
        if (includeMachineInfo) machineInfo = Environment.MachineName + " >> ";
        message = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", dateText, machineInfo, message);
        var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }
        try
        {
            using (var sw = File.AppendText(filename))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(message);
            }                
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The `catch` above might be where the exception is swallow. Some IOException could be thrown there. Really I think that should rarely happen (unless there is something wrong with the hard disk drive).

Comment: Can you try removing static from the core method? You should avoid putting a static modifier on anything that deals with persistence or state.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning these methods are just like helper methods, I don't really think it might matter here. All the arguments are consumed as read-only and just not shared everywhere else, also the issue here involves the code flow, not some wrong or unexpected value of something. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Sure, but if you have a minute and you're spinning your wheels in this, I'd recommend at least giving it a shot.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning OK thank you, I think the most possible cause of this involves the `Log.WriteOnToDay`, it might swallow some exception there, I'm really curious about what exception it could be. Maybe it need more test. I will update the question soon.

Comment: `Log` is static and being accessed by multiple threads, make sure that whatever it is doing in there is safe for multi-threading.  Its state could easily be getting trashed by multiple threads hitting it at the same time.

Comment: @BradleyUffner yes, I know about that, here there seems to have only 1 shared data `LastWrittenLogFileName` but that's not important in this case.

Comment: If both tasks happen to log at the exact same time, one could get a FileInUse exception.

Comment: You need to add synchronization to `LogForToday` around the `File.Append`. A simple `lock` should do it.

Comment: @sgmoore wow, that could be the cause, thanks.

Comment: @BradleyUffner yes that's one way to solve. But I've thought about changing the shared mode when appending file, it might be working here?

Comment: Actually, you need the `lock` around more than that.  You can get all kinds of race conditions around directory creation too... I'd just wrap the entire method body in a `lock`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner thank you, threading is too dangerous (really the Log class was written without awareness of threading, I just used it anyway without looking back in its code).

Comment: Yep. If you want to do logging properly, you should look in to using a Producer / Consumer Queue.

Comment: Why are you trying to write your own logging framework? There are plenty of very robust, free frameworks that have already solved these kinds of problems.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior because I like the simplicity, for small projects I always use my own :) it just need a bit more carefulness.

Comment: Your `Log` class is already more complicated than it could be if you were using a third-party logging framework, and now you're going to need to make it even more complicated to deal with locking. And you don't know what other issues logging frameworks have already solved that you're not even thinking of. If you like simplicity, then use a logging framework.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I think simple (small) projects should not put me in some complicated scenario in which the log might stop working (dealing with threading if being aware of it beforehand is just not too hard). The simplicity I mean here is there is just 1 file and I can just include it in the project. Also you can see that it handles the log path for me so that I don't have to think about it, what I expect is just some output logged in some easily-found place (right in the bin folder). So it's very handy. Of course for large project, I would go for logging frameworks :)

Comment: "I think simple (small) projects should not put me in some complicated scenario in which the log might stop working..." By trying to roll your own logging framework, you've just run into exactly that complicated scenario. And it's very easy to configure a logging framework to output to some easily-found place right in the bin folder. You can take my advice with a grain of salt, of course, but I've personally found any project big enough to merit logging is big enough to merit a logging framework.

Comment: If nothing else, writing your own logger will be a learning experience.  As long as you don't depend on it for "mission critical" production code, it won't really matter all that much.